Нужно ли обособление оборота в предложении?
Несомненно, эта идея(,) как лучший показатель богатства его воображения(,) и привлекла внимание.
И если да или нет, то почему нужно / не нужно?

Похоже на ДЗ... Если и так, то всё-таки: что сами-то предлагаете?

Правильно:
Несомненно, эта идея, как лучший показатель богатства его воображения, и привлекла внимание.

Оборот обособляется прежде всего по структуре предложения — произнести эту фразу без обособления просто невозможно.

Оборот имеет значение тождества (приравнивания) и при этом содержит оттенок причинного значения: эта идея, будучи показателем богатства его воображения...


Розенталь, Сравнительный оборот, пункт 3:
Сравнительный оборот может содержать в себе оттенок причинного значения: Васенда, как человек положительный и практический, нашёл невыгодным закреплённое место (Пом.) — ‘будучи человеком положительным’.
